# Error using broom::tidy on a linear mixed model created with lmerTest

Tags: r, lme4, broom

I am trying to use the `tidy` function in the *broom* R package to display results from a linear mixed model created with `lmer` from *lmerTest*.  I get an error and I don't know if it's from a bug or incorrectly using the library. Perhaps this isn't supposed to work, but in that case, what is recommended for a similar result? Here is my example:

```
> m1 = lme4::lmer(mpg ~ disp + (1|vs), data=mtcars)
> m2 = lmerTest::lmer(mpg ~ disp + (1|vs), data=mtcars)
> tidy(m1)
                     term    estimate   std.error statistic    group
1             (Intercept) 29.59985476 1.229719515 24.070411    fixed
2                    disp -0.04121512 0.004711833 -8.747152    fixed
3       sd_(Intercept).vs  0.00000000          NA        NA       vs
4 sd_Observation.Residual  3.25145449          NA        NA Residual
> tidy(m2)
Error in vector(type, length) : 
  vector: cannot make a vector of mode 'NULL'.
```

I am using R 3.5.0, lme4 1.1-17, lmerTest 3.0-1 and broom 0.4.4

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. Tested with `broom_0.4.2` and `lme4_1.1-13`. What version are you using?

Comment: I also can't reproduce the error (using `broom_0.4.4` and `lme4 1.1-17`).

Comment: Sorry, I added version information.

Comment: What does `environment(tidy)` return? Maybe try with `broom::tidy(m)`.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, in clean environment I can not reproduce either. Will check on adding packages and seeing what breaks it.

Comment: Aha, it was lmerTest that was causing the problem.  I will reformulate the question.